# Can you set a specific WiFi channel with an iOS/iPhone personal hotspot?

Tags: wifi, ios, tethering

Anytime when I using my iPhone as personal WiFi HotSpot (sharing 3G internet via WiFi) the iPhone selects channel #1 for this.

Is possible to use another channel number because the channel 1 is already used by another cable modem / WiFi router and turning on (and using) the hotspot on the iPhone causes noticeable degradation of the speed on the cable-WiFi router.

So the question: Is possible somewhat enforce another WiFi channel number for the hotspot on the iPhone? (e.g. 11 or soo)

Comment: Not without using a jailbreak application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - the OS picks channels algorithmically so you get what iOS chooses each time you enable personal hot spot.  I've seen personal hotspot pick channels 1, 6 and 11 on iOS 7 when in moderately busy wireless environments like this one with 26 advertising base stations (and a few hidden ones as well).

[image: Wireless Scan]

Comment: Accepting this too bad news... ;(

Answer (score 3):

Whilst you can't enforce a specific channel on iOS, it does attempt to select the best channel for the situation. I have found that a combination of standing directly next to the router and enabling/disabling Personal Hotspot until you get a channel you want seems to work well enough.

Alternatively, if you have control of the router, you could simply change the channel of the router to be 'out of the way'.

As well as this, if you have dynamic channel switching enabled on the router, turning on Personal Hotspot *then* standing next to the router for a bit should make the router change channel for you.

Comment: +1 for this "workaround". Wondering why apple isnt allow some "advanced" settings for a thing what is possible in any simple and lowcost wifi hotspot...

Comment: As you can see, the hotspot is picking what it wants as a good clear channel and your existing router suffers. I love the Wireless Diagnostic on OS X that let's you map SSID and signal strength to measure what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm,
Yes  i have that channel problem too.  i reserched and found that inssider program.
Serving to find out which channel your phone using or other wifi spots. Bad news is u cant edit phones hotspot channel unless its  jailbroken.(i didnt try that)
Using my phone with stock OS. İf you have ip4 and dont have ios7 u can try JB.
İF not meaning u have 4 and ios 7 never ever try to JB.